# Proper Up Navigation From Fragment to Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-navigation

I am currently working on an app that consists of a base activity that manages several fragments.  One of those fragments is a list which when clicking on an item launches a details activity.  I would like when I click on the home button ( Using ABS ) for the app to navigate back to the listfragment but instead it always navigates back to the fragment I specified as the default.

```
Base Activity
    Frag1 - Default
    Frag2
    Frag3 -> DetailsActivity
```

When home button is pressed from DetailsActivity I want to go back to Frag3 instead I go to Frag1.

Any help would be great.  Here is the code I have in the details activity to handle the home button being pressed.

Main Activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // set the Above View
    if (savedInstanceState != null)
        mContent = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState,               "mContent");
    if (mContent == null)
        mContent = new HomeFragment();

    // set the Above View
    setContentView(R.layout.content_frame);
    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame, mContent)
            .commit();

    // set the Behind View
    setBehindContentView(R.layout.menu_frame);
    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.menu_frame, new SlidingMenuFragment())
            .commit();

    // customize the SlidingMenu
    getSlidingMenu().setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "mContent", mContent);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

public void switchContent(Fragment fragment) {
    getSlidingMenu().showContent();

    mContent = fragment;
    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .addToBackStack("test")
            .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
            .commit();
}
```

Sub Activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Intercept the event --home-- in detail activity , calling 'finish()'.

Implement 'on activity result()' in frag#3.

You Will return from detail activity to frag3.

Comment: I was able to get this to work however, it doesn't seem like this is the best practice. I don't expect a result from the details activity so I would rather not use this method unless it is truly the only way.  Thanks for the trick though it certainly does work!

Comment: well then look at using an interface in frag3 to actually return to BaseActivity on the event frag#3.HOME, and then start Intent for DetailActivity from Base. When Detail Activity finish, use the frag transactionManager to 'add' frag#3 after Detail.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your fragments to the backstack. See [Implement Back Navigation for Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html#back-fragments)

Comment: I think the problem lies in that savedInstanceState is always null when I return to the main activity.  I added some more code above.

Answer (score 0):

What about passing an extra to your parent activity (Base Activity) like your fragment id?

Sub Activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
        case android.R.id.home:
        // Retrieve this Activiy's parent Up intent
        Intent upIntent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this);
        // Add the required Intent extras as appropriate
        upIntent.putExtra("KEY", id);
        NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, upIntent);

            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

`NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this)` is equivalent to calling `navigateUpTo(sourceActivity, getParentActivityIntent (sourceActivity))`.